# Get YouTube video comments in my website

Tags: web, youtube, embedding

In my website i got succeeded in embedding videos from YouTube but i'm not getting the comments made on that videos. So is there any way to get that comments embedded with the video in my website. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th easiest way to access YouTube data, without authentication or the YouTube API, is by using the YouTube Query URLS.

For Comments,  process this URL:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoId}/comments`

Additional meta data on the video can be accessed using processing this URL:

`http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$videoId}`